# How does activated carbon catalyse oxidation?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, spectroscopy

Context: I am doing an experiment on the quantitative analysis of ascorbic acid in a blackcurrent syrup using fluorescence spectroscopy. In order to do so, ascorbic acid was first oxidised into dehydroascorbic acid. Emission reading was then recorded.
An aliqout of the sample was taken and boric acid was added to form a complex that would be fluorescent inactive to account for other impurities that are fluorescent active and would interfere with the results. The loss in emission between the original sample and the sample with boric acid was used to deduce the amount of ascorbic acid present.

The reagents used were: acetic acid and sodium acetate as buffer, metaphosphoric acid, and activated carbon. In this scenario, how does activated carbon aid in the oxidation of ascorbic acid?

Also, I've done some searching online and found that the purpose of metaphosphoric acid was to prevent the atmospheric oxidation of ascorbic acid. Why would we want to prevent the atmospheric oxidation of ascorbic acid if what we wanted to achieve was to oxidise it anyway?